# nth Root of Product of Fractions

Tags: limits, infinite-product

Let $$f_n(x) = \left| \prod_{k=0}^n \left( x - \frac{k}{n} \right) \right|^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Based purely on examination of the graph below, which has $n=100$, it appears that for $x \not \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1], \; \, f_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ where $f$ is some continuous function.

I have been attempting to work towards identifying $f$, although unfortunately haven't really gotten anywhere. Otherwise some insight into proving (or disproving) any of the following observations would also be useful:

$f(0) = f(1) = e^{-1}$

$f(\frac{1}{2}-x) = f(\frac{1}{2}+x)$

$f$ has a minimum at $x = \frac{1}{2}$

Asymptotic behavior of $f$ as $|x| \to \infty$

I have also attempted to consider $\log f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n \log |x-\frac{k}{n}|$, but to no avail.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be the function represented by

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\prod_{k=0}^n\left(x-\frac kn\right)\right|^{1/n}$$

Next, note that

$$\left|\prod_{k=0}^n\left(x-\frac kn\right)\right|^{1/n}=e^{\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^n \log\left|\left(x-\frac kn\right)\right|}$$

The limit of the exponent is the Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \log|x-t|\,dt$, when $x\in [0,1]$ and is irrational.  For $x\in [0,1]$ and irrational, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \log|x-t|\,dt&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(\int_0^{x-\epsilon} \log(x-t)\,dt+\int_{x+\epsilon}^1 \log(t-x)\,dt\right)\\\\
&=x\log(x)-x+(1-x)\log(1-x)-(1-x)\\\\
&=x\log(x)+(1-x)\log(1-x)-1
\end{align}$$

and $f(x)=e^{-1}x^x\,(1-x)^{1-x}$.

---

If $x>1$, then $f(x)=e^{\int_0^1 \log(x-t)\,dt}=e^{-1}\frac{x^x}{(x-1)^{x-1}}$.

If $x<0$, then $f(x)=e^{\int_0^1 \log(t-x)\,dt}=e^{-1}\frac{(1-x)^{1-x}}{(-x)^{-x}}$.